# Keep Typeahead.js Results Window Open

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead.js to show an autocomplete box of results that are generated by a query sent to a server. I can't cache the data locally due to it's size and even a subset would be quite large to be useful. However, it takes about 500 ms to return results, which means that the results box disappears when another character is typed and then reappears with the new results. In some cases, the new results are nearly, if not, identical to the results that were returned previously. I would like to have typeahead keep the results window open until the new results are returned and then update the results window (possibly via hiding it, repopulation, and redisplay) as that would give a much better appearance contrasted to the noticeable blinking that is taking place now.

I've looked at the GitHub page for [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) and can't find anything there that looks useful and since I'm not a JavaScript master, I thought it would be good to ask if there is something else I can do to achieve what I'm after.

Comment: I've had good results with jQuery UI autocomplete. How many rows do you typically return from the db query?

Comment: @TimSPQR, I usually return 6 results.

Comment: So why couldn't you read everything, then have the autocomplete sort it out. I typically go to the db first, read as many as 200 rows, pass those rows to autocomplete and let it do its thing. VERY fast.

Comment: I'm working with more than 30,000 possible results and the autocomplete box will show an image, description, and title for each hit (HTML template). I'm using full-text search and a procedure to return ranked results.

Comment: Ok, so potentially large. So you could figure out how many characters are necessary to return a manageable result, and then pass the query at X characters. Or, you don't do autocomplete, just use a standard search. Or, you could subset the query to fewer columns, and then when a set is selected, a full query is made. Don't you wish you had Google's firepower? The entire web in an autocomplete box. :-)

Comment: I really wish I did...Alas, that is why I'm simply looking for a way to keep the box open. The 500 ms isn't an issue, the blinking is.